# Mute on mouse click down and unmute on mouse click release

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create a script that mutes all sound upon mouse click down,
and unmutes when I release the button (mouse click up), while retaining it's original Left Click function.

This is what I have:

```
~LButton::Send {Volume_Mute}
return
```

But it just mutes and unmutes every click.. it's not complete. I'm not quite sure how to put it..

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

My hotkey:

```
~*$LButton::
    SoundSet, +1, , mute
Return
~LButton Up::
    SoundSet, +1, , mute
Return
```

Still not sure if this is the best one for the job. =)